# How to update row in intermediate table in many to many relationship?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a many to many relationship beetween tables:

```
Banks -> BanksUsers <- Users
```

There is an row in table `BanksUsers`:

```
id | bank_id | user_id
1    1         2
```

How to update `bank_id for user_id = 2` using models in Laravel?

I tried this:

```
$users = Users::where("id", 2)->banks()->update("bank_id", 3);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create relationship in your Users table:

`return $this->belongsToMany('Banks', 'bank_user', 'user_id', 'bank_id');`

Then use sync method

$user->banks()->sync($data);

Comment: Where `$data` is?

Comment: `$data` should be an array of `bank_id`s. Example: `$user->banks()->sync([1, 4, 7])` will make sure that the `$user` has only entries in the `BanksUsers` table with `bank_id` 1, 4 and 7. All other entries will be removed. If necessary, new ones are added.

Comment: I use this in model:  `return $this->belongsToMany(Banks::class);`